# Problema com maior e menor (while)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Elabore um algoritmo que leia dez valores informados pelo usuário e informe qual o maior e qual o menor valor lido.

```py
cont = 0
n = 0
maior = n
menor = n
while cont < 3:
    n = int(input('Insira os números: >>> '))
    if n > maior :
        maior = n
    elif menor > n :
        menor = n
    cont = cont + 1
    print(menor,maior)
```

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: o código resulta sempre com o menor = 0, eu imagino que sejo por conta do n = 0 na 2° linha, mas se eu tiro o n de lá a variavel fica como se não fosse definida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no fato de você iniciar as variáveis maior e menor como 0 (no caso deveria iniciar como o primeiro valor lido pra comparar, já que podem haver valores negativos, menores que 0) e a indentação do print que mostra o menor e o maior que deveria mostrar apenas no final, o código ficaria assim:

```
cont = 0
while cont < 10:
    n = int(input('Insira os números: >>> '))
    if cont == 0 :
        menor=n
        maior=n
    if n > maior :
        maior = n
    elif menor > n :
        menor = n
    cont = cont + 1
print(menor,maior)
```